# Pull data from regular tab content

Tags: vba, web-scraping

This code written by QHarr for another question was working, but in my Html body code I have regular tabs and mobile tabs.

This code is pulling both Url's of href codes in "regular tab content" and "Mobile tab content". I want to pull only regular tab content href url's. There are two nodes related to each other in the HTML tree structure.

```html
<!-- regular tabs content -->

<div class="Right_Side" id="Work">
        <button class="btn-success primary btn" data-bind="visible: !$root.providerShouldAcceptDecline() &amp;&amp; !isOutsourced(), click : add">Consolidate</button>
        <div class="download">
        <a class="btn-default" href="#" data-bind="click : download, visible: $root.ViewModel.data().length > 0">
        </a>
        </div>
<div class="link">
            <a class="action" href="#" data-bind="click: $root.ViewModel.showDelete"></a>
            <a title="Before.jpg"class="app-action" style="padding-left: 0px;" href="example.com/Documents/Id=FileName=Check.jpg" target="_blank" data-bind="text:fileName">Check</a>
            <span class="data">
            <span data-bind="text:uploadDate">Second Month </span>
            </span>
            </div>
<div class="link">
            <a class="action" href="#" data-bind="click: $root.ViewModel.showDelete"></a>
            <a title="Before.jpg" class="app-action" style="padding-left: 0px;" href="example.com/Documents/Id=FileName=Check.jpg" target="_blank" data-bind="text:fileName">Check</a>
            <span class="data">
            <span data-bind="text:uploadDate">Second Month </span>
            </span>
       </div>
</div>
```

```
With IE
   .Visible = True
   .navigate "Example.com"
    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long
    Set aNodeList = IE.document.querySelectorAll(".app-action[href]")
    For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 2, 4) = aNodeList.item(i)
    Next
   'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
End With
```

Comment: Will there only be one result or always the first of two? And which of the two a tags within the relevant node?

Comment: There will be multiple results and need to pull all  "<a title" tags. I need the list of urls in href. Below is the example list the i need from the above html code. Also i have updated the html code for your reference.

(href="https://example.com/Documents/GetTempLink?attachmentId=FileName=Before.jpg
href="https://example.com/Documents/GetTempLink?attachmentId=FileName=Before.jpg
href="https://example.com/Documents/GetTempLink?attachmentId=FileName=After.jpg
href="https://example.com/Documents/GetTempLink?attachmentId=FileName=After.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure your html is accurately copy pasted?

Comment: If you right click inspect element on the <div class="Right Pannel" id="Work"> and take the entire node up to the closing </div> it is similar?

Comment: No sir, I edited URLs and replaced some text due to restrictions... But what the html code copied is in correct format..

Comment: Did you find any issue with the code... please let me know...

Comment: Instinct tells me something might be off. The best I see is querySelectorAll("#Work [title]")  with HTML as shown. This brings back one node too many if I understand you correctly. The last node would need to be ignored so you would loop to .Length -2. However, for other use cases I have no idea if this would hold true. Doesn't feel particularly robust.

Comment: QHarr, This is working fine and pulls the exact data of [title], but this is pulling all the two nodes data. if i use .Length-2 only 1 row is reduced. EX: In ("#Work[title]) if i need to pull 6 titles then it is pulling total 6+5 titles since i used .Length-2, if i use .Length-3 it is puling 6+4. Can you modify little bit to pull only 6 titles that means only from the first node.

Comment: For i = 0 To (ie.document.querySelectorAll("#Work [title]").Length- 2 ) /2   assuming even length .   ?

Comment: Thanks a lot QHarr, that worked fine, no issues.. and this time i learned something new from you. I'm not sure how to vote this post so i voted for comments which are useful to research. Please do let me know what i did is correct or not.

Comment: I will put it as an answer and you can choose whether to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an attribute = value selector combined with id selector for parent node:

```
For i = 0 To (ie.document.querySelectorAll("#Work [title]").Length- 2 ) /2 'assuming even length
```

html looks a little off potentially and so the above simply halves the returned nodelist (assumes equal split therefore between two tabs)